How to stop containers with docker-compose down? when it's not working
nginx-nodejs-redis-web1-1   | Web application is listening on port 5000
nginx-nodejs-redis-web2-1   | Web application is listening on port 5000
nginx-nodejs-redis-nginx-1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2024:05:40:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 28 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx-nodejs-redis-nginx-1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2024:05:40:49 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 150 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx-nodejs-redis-nginx-1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2024:05:40:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 28 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx-nodejs-redis-nginx-1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2024:05:40:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 28 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx-nodejs-redis-nginx-1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2024:05:40:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 28 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx-nodejs-redis-nginx-1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2024:05:40:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 28 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
[+] Running 0/2
 ⠿ Container nginx-nodejs-redis-redis-1  Error while Stopping                                                                                                                               14.0s
 ⠿ Container nginx-nodejs-redis-nginx-1  Error while Stopping                                                                                                                               14.0s
[+] Running 0/4
 ⠿ Container nginx-nodejs-redis-web1-1   Error while Killing                                                                                                                                10.0s
 ⠿ Container nginx-nodejs-redis-nginx-1  Error while Killing                                                                                                                                10.0s
 ⠿ Container nginx-nodejs-redis-redis-1  Error while Killing                                                                                                                                10.0s
 ⠿ Container nginx-nodejs-redis-web2-1   Error while Killing   
^C^C

**This is where I got stuck even by pressing ctrl+c, ctrl+d is not working I am stuck here! **
I tried ctrl+c, ctrl+d and even exit but no luck!
^C^Cexit
exit


open a new terminal in the same directory and run docker-compose stop
# Stop services only
docker-compose stop

# Stop and remove containers, networks..
docker-compose down 

source
otherwise, run docker ps. This will show all the running containers.
copy the relevant container id and run docker stop <container id>

Already tried none of them worked! any other options? or shortcuts?

in docker desktop you can manually stop the container

Didn't install docker desktop, working on CLI only so thanks for the idea will give it a shot and tell you.
